# Swiftui ImagePicker trigger api post photo

Tags: post, swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller

Im trying to write a code for profile photo posting in swiftui. I have found the example of select the photo from the gallery. Now I'm trying to add a HTTP request to post the image to the API. However I have no idea where should I locate my API post. **It shall be able to trigger the api post after the user selected the photo from imagePicker**. Anyone have idea about it? Thank you.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isShowPicker: Bool = false
    @State var image: Image? = Image("profile")
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    image?
                        .resizable()
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.isShowPicker.toggle()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowPicker) {
                ImagePicker(image: self.$image)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Pick Image")
        }
    }
}
```

Image Picker

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode)
    var presentationMode
    
    @Binding var image: Image?
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        
        @Binding var presentationMode: PresentationMode
        @Binding var image: Image?
        
        init(presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>, image: Binding<Image?>) {
            _presentationMode = presentationMode
            _image = image
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            print(image! as Any)
            presentationMode.dismiss()
            
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            presentationMode.dismiss()
        }
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(presentationMode: presentationMode, image: $image)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here and below instead of use `Image` (as passing here & there) use `UIImage`, then you'll be able to convert it into data and post

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isShowPicker: Bool = false

    // now you store UIImage, so can use/pass in action `.jpegData(...`
    @State var image: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "profile")
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Image(uiImage: self.image ?? UIImage())
```